# Errors in installing Visual Studio 2015, regarding "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, error-handling, installation

I am stuck since 2 days with this simple installation process of Visual Studio 2015 from my university portal (vs_communityENUS.exe which is a 3260 KB application). I am not new to installation and troubleshooting but this one has got me insane.

Every time I install it it throws me errors:

1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23918 : Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel.
2. Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
   Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.24210 : The installer failed. Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel. Error code: 0x80070666
3. Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
   Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.24210 : The installer failed. Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel. Error code: 0x80070666
4. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23918 : Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel.

I checked my control panel but I did not find any files with the above name. Than, I got this [amazing link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qi0deGqmo2g) that helped me remove any previous version of visual studio I have in my machine but a fresh installation after that also threw same errors.

I am badly stuck, what I want is a simple visual studio version compatible to windows 8.1 and can successfully integrate with opencv, qt and vtk.

Any help in this regard is highly and respectfully appreciated.

Comment: Why install VS2015 when VS2017 is available?

Comment: Is VS2017 compatible to opencv and vtk and qt? I heard its not :(

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It may be a better choice if you have pre-built versions of libraries that were built with VS2015.

Comment: Okay! I will give it a try!

Comment: The 3260 KB application is merely the bootstrapper; it will download components as required.

Comment: Any idea where can I locate the files throwing error in my machine instead of just control panel (because its not visible to me there) , I also did regedit but got buffed away

Comment: @MSalters fair point

Comment: @MSalters I know that and I tried the using complete set up also from microsoft's webiste but same results and its quite understandable why

Comment: Well! I installed VS2017 and I hope I can successfully link opencv, qt. vtk with it :) Thank guys !!

Answer (score 12):

Do you have the Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable installed before the VS 2015 installation? If so, please try to uninstall the Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable then install the VS 2015 again per [this similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/14701/visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015-ca.html)

If not and you cannot find the higher version of the VS Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable under Control Panel, please [use MsiInv to gather information about what is installed on a computer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer/), if it is confirmed that a higher version is existing, then you can ignore this warning information to use VS 2015.

Comment: Well, to be on the safe side, I removed every damm files from visual studio's previous version and than tried installing VS 2015 version 14, but the problem I think was with the location of installation (I guess). 32-bit and 64-bit packages create files and registry keys in different locations (WOW64). Installer has a bug when evaluating the file installation conditions for a 32-bit package in 64 bit laptop. I don't enough time to ponder about it right so I settled for VS2017.

Comment: Had trouble installing MySQL products as MySQL Server requires VC++ 2015 Redistributable and I didn't have them. But I had all lower and 2017 VC++ installed. So just removed 2017 versions and been able to install 2015 and later installed 2017 again. Now everything is cool.

Comment: just remove every "Visual Studio C++ Redist pack" with version above your installed Visual Studio. Mine VS2015 installation was blocked by VS2015-2019 MSVC++ Redist pack.

Answer (score 3):

There are some known issues with Visual Studio 2017 redistributables interfering with VS2015 redistributables. Temporarily uninstalling them might allow you to install the whole of VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different strategies to get this to be fixed, but I found a program that installed all the various visual c++ packages without a hitch and fixed my problems.

https://github.com/abbodi1406/vcredist